# ajax passing string getting array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel Framework, and I'm trying to create an Ajax request, so I can send the Form data to the Controller.
The thing is, I'm passing a string but in the controller, when I try JSON_decode it says that I'm giving it an array and not a string.
What am I doing wrong?

View (ajax)

```
function getData() {
   var name = $('#name').val();
   var tin = $('#tin').val();
   var password = $('#password').val();
   var currency = $('#currency').val();

   var data = {"name": name, 'tin': tin, 'password': password, 'currency': currency};
   var obj = JSON.stringify({"name": name, 'tin': tin, 'password': password, 'currency': currency});
   console.log(obj);
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "teste",
      data: obj,
      success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
      }
   });
}
```

Controller:

```
 $data = $_POST;
    //$string = json_encode($data);
    $test = json_decode($data);
    echo $test->name ;
    //echo "data: $string, gravada com sucesso!";
    die;
```

If someone could help me...

Just solved.

```
$.ajax({ 
   type: "POST",
   url: "teste",
   data: {"name": name, 'tin': tin, 'password': password, 'currency': currency},
   success: function (result) {
      alert(result);
    }
});
```

And in the controller, I encoded and then decoded..and it worked
Thanks :)

Comment: $_POST is an array, change `json_decode` to `json_encode`

Comment: it says that I'm trying to get a  property of non-object

Comment: I'd just started learning laravel

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `JSON.stringify`

Remove `JSON.stringify` and directly pass `data`

or If you want to read in json format, then

`url: "1.php",
 data: {"key":obj},`

Answer (score 1):

In your example if you want to pass json string in than you need to pass **OBJ** as a param:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = {"name": name, 'tin': tin, 'password': password, 'currency': currency};
var obj = JSON.stringify({"name": name, 'tin': tin, 'password': password, 'currency': currency});

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?=g('base_url')?>home/index",
data: "obj="+obj, // add as a param
success: function (result) {
alert(result);
}
});
</script>
```

In PHP, you can get object in `$_POST` as:

```
$data = $_POST['obj'];
$test = json_decode($data);
echo $test->name;
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Second solution you have already updated in your question.